# What's wrong with my Enzyme/Mocha test?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

React component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class Simple extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="Simple">
      Result: {this.props.value * 4}
    </div>
  }
}

Simple.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.number,
};
```

Test:

```
describe('<Simple />', _ => {
  it('should display', done => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Simple />);

    expect(wrapper.find('div.Simple')).to.have.length(1);
    done();
  });

  it('should quadruple a value passed into it', done => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Simple value={3} />);

    expect(wrapper.contains(<div className="Simple">Result: 12</div>)).to.equal(true);
    done();
  })
});
```

The first test passes, the second (quadruple a value) fails. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT:

If I modify the component to just return this:

```
return <div className="Simple">
  Result:
</div>
```

And the test as follows:

```
expect(wrapper.contains(
  <div className="Simple">
    Result:
  </div>
)).to.equal(true);
```

Then it passes. So it's when I introduce calculating props that the test fails. I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Do you need a semi colon at the end of the second it?

Comment: Nope, that's definitely not the problem.

Comment: can we see the `ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage value=22 />, mountNode);` I am kinda new to node So i'm looking for the execution workflow defined here :: https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: I guarantee that's not the problem either. I can see the component rendering on the page. Showing the code wouldn't help anyway.. it's not standard React.

Comment: I wonder if I need to use `render` instead of `shallow`? And then `expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('Result: 12')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
  it('should quadruple a value passed into it', done => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Simple value={3} />);

    expect(wrapper.contains(<div className="Simple">Result: {12}</div>)).to.equal(true);
    done();
  })
```

This is because there are two child elements in the div.  You can see this if you use `console.log(wrapper.find('div').childAt(1).text())` this gives you 12.

`shallow` is basically a wrapper for the shallow renderer from `react-addons-test-utils`.  What this does is execute your components render method and returns the resulting react elements. In this case react would create two elements one for `Result:` and one for `12`.  Dan Abramov has an [excellent post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) that describes exactly a react element is.

In your test that didn't work you were looking for a div with one text node but what was rendered was a div with two text nodes. By putting 12 in curly braces you have forced it into a new text node

Comment: That worked! I guess in a way that makes sense, since the `12` is number and is technically JavaScript...?

Comment: I think the reason is the div has two children. In the DOM text within a div is a text node. You can have more than one text node within an element. In your test that didn't work you were looking for a div with one text node but what was rendered was a div with two text nodes. By putting 12 in curly braces you have forced it into a new text node

Comment: Gotcha. Also, using `render` instead of `shallow`, and then looking for `"Result: 12"` also does the trick.

Comment: Yeah `render` renders to html strings so the nodes concept disappears.  `shallow` is basically a wrapper for the shallow renderer from `react-addons-test-utils`.  What this does is execute your components render method and returns the resulting react elements. In this case react would create two elements one for `Result:` and one for `12`

Comment: This is an excellent read to learn more about react elements: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html